# "To get stuck" OR "to become stuck": Which one is idiomatic in the case of "a bus on the snowy ground"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adjectives, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

This sentence is under one of the pictures on the BBC news about the snowfall in England.

**"Here, two buses become stuck in snow on Muswell Hill in north London."**

**"To become stuck"** sounds interesting to me. Would'nt we normally say **"to get stuck"**?

Comment: 'Become' is more formal than 'get' and in this context means the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Become' is more formal than 'get' and in this context means the same.
> — Michael Harvey (comment)